# Not showing text in html with POST request

Tags: python, html, django, web, django-views

Im trying to take a text from a text box and print it on my html file, but it doesn't work.

Here is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import InputForm
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    form = InputForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form })

def post(request):
    form = InputForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        text = form.cleaned_data['post']

        args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
    return render(request, 'index.html', args)
```

Here is my index.html

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Write a sentence</h1>

<form method="post" action="">
    {{ form }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit", name="save">Generate</button>
</form>
<h2>
    {{ text }}
</h2>

{% endblock %}
```

forms.py

'''
from django import forms

class InputForm(forms.Form):
input = forms.CharField(label="Text", max_length=1000)
'''

Im doing all stuff by tutorial and getting POST request in terminal, but unfortunately text doesn't appear

Comment: Share your `urls.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are firing the `home` function again. You should handle the POST case there as well:

```
def home(request):
    text = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InputForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            text = form.cleaned_data['post']
    else:
        form = InputForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form, 'text': text})
```

Comment: Giving me KeyError: 'post'

Comment: @PrabhuEgorus: likely because your form... has no field named `post`...